# as3/AIR HTMLLoader crappy fonts on windows

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm developing an AIR multitouch app for windows. the whole starling/flash stuff works great. now I tried to load an HTML File inside a window.

the index.html file lays directly in the air root, although the htmlstyle.css.

```
@font-face { font-family: 'C';
             src: url('font/FrutigerLTCom-Condensed.ttf') 
             }

@font-face { font-family: 'B';
             src: url('font/FrutigerLTCom-BoldCn.ttf') 
            }
```

ok, in my local browser it looks fine. inside the air app, the text looks frayed and pixeled.

where's the problem? didn't the HTMLLoader find the fonts or are there some security issues?

regards

Answer (score 1):

I once had quality issues with StageWebView. Maybe use StageWebWiew(true) when creating new StageWebView object. This will use device's default browser (e.g. Chrome or FireFox) for rendering html stuff, instead of AIR's built-in engine.

Comment: I didn't use webview, I use HTMLLOader like html= new HTMLLoader() and then add it with  addChild(html);